# Isolate Static Meshes from Blueprints and Materials

Tags: python, unreal-engine4

I want to run an automated rename process for assets in an Unreal engine 4 project using Python, however, I only want to rename the Static Meshes, and then the Materials separately, leaving the blueprints alone.

I have looked through the Python API documentation but can't seem to find a function that cycles through the assets and creates a list for each object type.  So far I have a function that retrieves all the assets in the contents folder, and puts them in a list.  I want a list for each of the object types

```
asset_names = unreal.EditorAssetLibrary.list_assets(asset_location)
```

but what I want is something more like

```
staticmesh_names = unreal.PythonFunction.list_objects(asset_location, StaticMesh)
material_names = unreal.PythonFunction.list_objects(asset_location, Material)
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: According to the docs `EditorAssetLibrary.list_assets` returns a list of strings. Looks like you will have to load the asset, check the asset type and remove it from the list if it is not the desired type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static_mesh_data = unreal.AssetRegistryHelpers.get_asset_registry().get_assets_by_class("StaticMesh")
static_mesh_objects = [data.get_asset() for data in static_mesh_data]
```

The returned objects should have a .rename() function

If you're going to use  Paulo Scardine's function, you can use this to easily filter out the class type you want:

`unreal.EditorFilterLibrary.by_class(loaded_assets, unreal.StaticMesh)`